# Cordova project is not getting created

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, cordova-cli

I am using mac os yosemite. After installing cordova, I was trying to create project using

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

My command get stuct at some point and showing

```
Downloading cordova library for www...
```

Then I uninstalled cordova and updated npm using

```
sudo npm update npm -g
```

after update I again installed cordova. This time it get instaled with one warning.

```
npm WARN engine npm@1.4.28: wanted: {"node":">=0.8","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.10.13","npm":"2.1.18"})
```

But I am still unable to create project it is still stuck at the same point (i.e. Downloading cordova library for www...)

I really don't know what to do in this.
My npm version is 2.1.18.
Any help?

Comment: are you under a proxy?

Comment: No, I am not on proxy.